# Is it possible to replace tildes representing empty lines with another character?

Tags: vimscript

I'm writing a plugin which needs to replace the empty line tildes with with a '.' character in a single window split. Is this possible to do with Vimscript?

Comment: If memory serves, this question was asked once, and the answer was “not without recompiling vim”—I’ll have to find it though

Comment: The best you can do is `hi NonText ctermfg=bg guifg=bg`

Comment: @Matt In recent versions of Vim (since 7.4.2213), there's a specific highlighting group for it: `EndOfBuffer`

Comment: Since [8.2.2508](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2508), you can hide the tilde by setting the [`'fillchars'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#'fillchars') option: `let &fillchars ..= ',eob: '`.  See also https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/28994/can-i-change-the-ugly-indicator-after-eol

Comment: My bad.  You don't want to hide them, you want to replace them.  So, try this instead:  `let &fillchars ..= ',eob:.'`.