# Can I change the ugly indicator after EOL (~)

Tags: margin

A tilde appears on the terminal if the file contain less lines than the screen currently displays. I was wondering if it is possible to remove them or replace them with something more beautiful (maybe a single line of underscores or something)

Here is an empty file full of tildes on a new vim without even a `vimrc`:
[image: Here is an empty vim window with the ugly tildes]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I believe based on `:help filler-lines` that these are hard-coded in the source, but I can't find a reference on that

Comment: Also if someone with higher score see this: I believe I put a wrong tag as there where no tags about cosmetics ,I would propose one

Comment: The best tag I could find is margin and the handful of questions associated with it do  suggest, IMO, that it's appropriate (though maybe not perfect).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since [8.2.2508](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.2508), you can hide the tilde by setting the [`'fillchars'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27fillchars%27) option:

```
let &fillchars ..= ',eob: '
```

Credit to [Yegappan Lakshmanan](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/29827/yegappan-lakshmanan) for submitting the PR [#7832](https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/7832).

Comment: I will change my accepted answer as this one is a little bit more accurate(even though  Quasimodos answer was fine for non-opaque terminals and Matts answer was very similar but neovim specific)

Answer (score 4):

I'm with Ben here: The tilde seems to be hardcoded. However, you can set their foreground color to match the background color so that they effectively disappear:

```
:hi EndOfBuffer ctermfg=black
```

Comment: That is good enough for now , is it a good idea to open an issue on vim/nvim to make this configurable ?

Comment: There is already an open feature request: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3820

Answer (score 3):

To be fair, in Neovim you can.

```
set fillchars+=eob:*
```

Also to note `:h 'fillchars'` in Neovim is local to window.